# Addclass on delay for a list

Tags: jquery, list, addclass

I am rendering a list using a backbone view. After the view is rendered I would like to loop through the list elements and then add a class to one li at a time (removing it from the previous one each time).

So far my code looks like this:

```
  onRender: function() {
    $('ul > li').each(function(i, element) {
      $(element).delay(i * 50000).toggleClass('fly-in-out')
    })
  }
```

However when the view loads all li have the fly-in-out class.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding class after random delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762920/adding-class-after-random-delay)

Comment: `toggleClass` is not an animation function, so it is not added to the fx queue. The simplest solution would be to just use `setTimeout`.

Comment: You could use `promise` and make a recursive call when the `toggleClass` method is done. `$(this).toggleClass('fly-in-out', 1000).promise().done(function(){alert("done")})`

Comment: or you can put toggleClass() in queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using delay, you need to put code in queue:

```
onRender: function () {
    $('ul > li').each(function (i, element) {
        $(element).delay(i * 50000).queue(function (next) {
            $(this).toggleClass('fly-in-out');
            next();
        });
    })
}
```

Or use a timeout:

```
onRender: function () {
    $('ul > li').each(function (i, element) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(element).toggleClass('fly-in-out');
        }, i * 50000);
    })
}
```

Comment: Both seem to just add a class to the first li

Answer (score 0):

your `$(element).delay` refers to only one element, not all of them. this is going through and applying the class to each element one at a time without accessing any of the others